# Eclipse + GWT 2.8.1. : Changes to *.ui.xml files don't show up although super dev mode is active

Tags: gwt, gwt-super-dev-mode

When I change a ui.xml file (e.g. change css styles), these changes don't show up in the application.
The only way to get the changes visible is in Eclipse to choose 
Project-> Clean ... and to remove and recompile the whole project.

My settings:
-noserver -remoteUI "${gwt_remote_ui_server_port}:${unique_id}" -logLevel INFO -war "${workspace_loc:NewComApp/war}" -codeServerPort 9998 com.myapp.MyApp
[image]

My tomcat (alhtough I understand that this does not influence the superdevmode):
[image]

Anyone experiencing the same problem. 
This makes iterations during development very slow, because compiling the whole project because of some minor changes to the layout seems ridiculous.

The ui.xml files are located in the same package as the java source files:
[image]
Any advice on this?

Comment: where are your ui.xml files are located?

Comment: in the same directory as the java source files. I added the screesnhot to the question above.

Comment: I found the following: Building the project provides files in the directory bin/com/myapp/etc. There there you find also ui.xml. files. If I change the ui.xml file there the changes are immediately visible using the dev mode. Where do I set that Project Build in Eclipse produces in /bin?

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and a little help from a friend I want to describe the solution.
First of all you need to understand that SuperDevMode (like DevMode) translates what it finds on the classpath of the JVM where the SuperDevMode runs.

So for the solution in Eclipse it is necessary to point the classpath to the source directory.

For this you need to open the config dialog of your SuperDevMode:
[image]

1. Means make *super* sure that your source comes first!!
2. Means that you must make sure all your project and libs are available

For 2. You need to open "Java Build Path" select "Order and Export" your Project Properties in Eclipse.

[image]

After that you you just hit F5 in eclipse to see any changes (ui.xml or java code) instantly compiled by SuperDevMode compiler instead of Eclipse Project Build compiler

Along with a tomcat installation this lots of time.